# Rails controller test with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I an trying to organize code by making partial `html.erb` files that are shared frequently(e.g. `_form.html.erb`)

I want to check whether my partial code works well with different models/controllers, so I am manually doing CRUD from the views.

It would be nicer to test my code automatically using `Rspec` but I have no idea. Can anyone give me some guidance how to test controller code with `Rspec`?

Comment: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec

Comment: To elaborate on what @max said, the convention in Rails is not to test controllers, it's to test features. (essentially ensuring the happy path functions as expected) The old way was to test controllers but not anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test controller and views together you write [*feature specs*](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec) and [*request specs*](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec) .

Request specs are lower level specs where you send HTTP requests to your application and write expectations (aka assertions in TDD lingo) about the response. They are a wrapper around `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`. Request specs should be considered the replacement for controller specs, the use of which are discouraged by by the RSpec and Rails teams.

```
# spec/requests/products_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe "Products", type: :request do
  describe "GET /products" do
     let!(:products) { FactoryBot.create_list(:product, 4) }
     it "contains the product names" do
        get "/products"
        expect(response).to include products.first.name
        expect(response).to include products.last.name
     end
  end
end
```

Feature specs are higher level specs that focus on the user story. They often serve as acceptance tests. They use a browser simulator named Capybara which emulates a user clicking his way through the application. Capybara can also run headless browsers (headless chrome, firefox, phantom js, webkit etc) and "real" browsers through selenium. The minitest equivalent is `ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase` but RSpec features do not wrap it (it took minitest/testunit years to catch up here).

```
# Gemfile
gem 'capybara'
```

```
# spec/features/products_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.feature "Products" do
  let!(:products) { FactoryBot.create_list(:product, 4) }

  scenario "when a user views a product" do
    visit '/'
    click_link 'Products'
    click_link products.first.name
    expect(page).to have_content products.first.name
    expect(page).to have_content products.first.description
  end
end
```

This specs tests the products#index and products#show action as well as the root page and the associated views.

Both types of specs have their strengths and weaknesses. Feature tests are good for testing large swaths of the application but are heavy. Request specs are faster and its easier to replicate a specific request that causes a bug/issue but you're basically just matching HTML with regular expressions which is highly limited.

Answer (score -1):

To check whether partial code works well with different models/controllers. You can add `render_views` in controller specs.

How to test controller code with Rspec? 
Read the official doc https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs

And this page may help: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/how-we-test-rails-applications

Comment: Writing controller specs is discouraged. That article is 6 years old and badly out of date.

Comment: Hi @max, he is asking for the controller test, then I did tell what he wants to know. And that article updated on 2019.